# Post Request from express to mongoDB

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

I am trying to post the information to the mongoDB with Express. All connections to DB are working fine, because get Request works

In my server.js I have defined the Schema

```
var todoSchema = new Schema({
    taskName: String,
    createdAt: Date,
    isDone: Boolean,
    prioraty: String
  }, {
    collection: 'tasks'
  });

var Model = mongoose.model('Model', todoSchema);
```

And then the app.post Request

```
app.post('/tasks', function(req, res) {
  var savedata = new Model({
    'taskName': req,
    'isDone': false,
    'createdAt': Date.now(),
    'prioraty': 'medium'
  }).save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (result) {
      res.json(result)
    }
  })
});
```

and this doesn't work at all...

In my frontend I call it by pressing the button, but nothing happens..

```
  postTask(task) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/tasks', task);
  }
```

How could I fix it? As mentioned, the GET request works fine, so I hope I am on right way...

So here is get Request for example

```
app.get('/tasks', (req, res) => {
  Model.find({
   // 'request': query
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) {
      res.json(result)
    } else {
      res.send(JSON.stringify({
        error : 'Error'
      }))
    }
     })
    });
```

Comment: are you `Subscribing` to it in component

Comment: which version of `angular` you are using? you should `subscribe` your `post request`

Comment: Adding the error message for the `POST` request as well as a sample of the `task` object you are sending in the post request is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your `POST`, `taskName` is a string based on your Schema, but you are passing it the complete `req` object. It should be what ever the property in the `req.body` is like `req.body.taskName` if that is what you are passing in your request.

Answer (score 1):

**First you need to recieve your response in frontend**

**In service:**

```
postTask(task) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/tasks', task);
}
```

**If you are using `angularjs`(angular 1+)**

You need to use `then` and `catch` to recieve the `response`

**In controller:**

```
this.service.postTask(task).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

**If you are using `angular`(angular 2+)**

You need to use `subscribe` as `this.http` returns `observable`

**In Component:**

```
this.service.postTask(task).subscribe( response => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

---

Second, as @andrew mentioned,

**`taskName` you should send `string` since you have `taskName` schema as `string`**

```
var todoSchema = new Schema({
    taskName: String,
})
```

**Update:**

> req.body Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request
>   body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use
>   body-parsing middleware such as body-parser

The following example shows how to use `body-parsing middleware` to populate `req.body`.

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    app.post('/tasks', function(req, res) {
       console.log(req.body)
    });
```

[**Here is Documentation of body-parser**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot, one more question - my request body is now empty...so how could I fix this?     'taskName': req, So, for example, if I write 'taskName':"test3", it works fine, but I can't pass the argument from function

Comment: can you console `req.body` , try `req.body.taskName`

Comment: or `req.params` if you `console.log(req)` you ll get to know what are present

Comment: you need to use `bodyParser` to get `req.body` please check the updated answer. you need to `npm install body-parser --save`

Comment: I am already using it... my console.log gives me empty object {}, if I try to console req.body

Comment: can you send what you are sending from `frontend`. `console.log(task)` in `front-end`

Comment: So, in my service I have a function  postTask(task) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/tasks', task);
  }   And then in component I have clickEvent on btn like this   postData(data) {
    this.service.postTask(data).subscribe( (res) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

Comment: And as I click the button the console.log gives me the right value, but I can't understand why it will be not passed to the app.post function in the backend

Comment: can you `console.log(task)` in `postTask` from service before api call

Comment: check [try setting headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163787/angular-2-http-post-nodejs-express) once and set headers

Comment: @AnnaF what does your post HTTP Service look like in Angular? Also have you tried using Postman to test the Node API by itself?

Comment: it is fine even if you are not using `service`, are you `using` `angular2`, please add `component code`